# tag-trends: a web app for viewing the popularity of Stack Overflow tags

Tags: app, website, typescript

### About:

[tag-trends](http://sotagtrends.com) is a web app that lets you visualize the popularity of Stack Overflow tags over time. Just enter a tag and you can see how many questions were asked about it each month.

### Screenshot

[image: tag-trends screenshot]

#### Download / Install:

tag-trends is available at: http://sotagtrends.com

#### Platform:

Runs in:
Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Internet Explorer (tested in IE11)

### Contact:

Rob McDiarmid

robianmcd@gmail.com

[@robianmcd](https://twitter.com/RobIanMcd)

#### License:

MIT

### Code:

This app is written in TypeScript with Angular2.

To get the data the app has to lookup every single question and store it's tags in my own database. Due to the quotas on the Stack Exchange APIs it took a few weeks to collect all that data but now that I have it I just have a script that runs once an hour to pull in any new questions.

The source is on GitHub at [github.com/robianmcd/tag-trends](https://github.com/robianmcd/tag-trends).